# What is the point density of a point sampling pattern in this context?

Tags: probability-theory, measure-theory, sampling, monte-carlo

I'm trying to understand the following assertion which is made in [this paper](https://www.cs.huji.ac.il/w%7Eraananf/projects/kdm/) on p. 3:

> In $d$-dimensional space the point density, defined as the number of points per unit volume, is inversely proportional to the $d$-th power of the inter-point distance.

The paper is about generating a point cloud such that the point density is $p$ (and some spatial characteristics of the cloud are satisfied).

I'm only interested in $d=2$ and the domain $\Omega=[0,1)^2$. Let $p$ be a probability density function on $[0,1)^2$. What I could imagine what is being meant is the following: Let $k\in\mathbb N$ and $X_1,\ldots,X_k$ be $[0,1)^2$-valued (independent?) random variables distributed according to $p$. Define the random measure $$\zeta(B):=\left|\left\{i\in\left\{1,\ldots,k\right\}:X_i\in B\right\}\right|\;\;\;\text{for }B\in\mathcal B([0,1)^2).$$ Then $\zeta(B)$ is the number of (random) points $X_i$ in $B\in\mathcal B([0,1)^2)$.

Now what is the "point density" $\rho$? Is it a density (with respect to which measure) of $\zeta(B)$?

**EDIT**: Maybe I should ask in general: If samples are distributed according to $p$, what is the "point density" of the corresponding sample points?

Comment: I find the wording of the authors confusing. "Number of points" suggests that the dominating measure is the counting measure. On the other hand, "volume" is suggestive of the Lebesgue measure. Maybe they are using the word 'density' in a loose sense. Did you try to reach out to the authors?

Comment: @Idontgetit I guess they are using the definition given in Definition 8/9 on p. 5 of [this document](https://www.tdx.cat/bitstream/handle/10803/394025/2014_Rodriguez_Cortes_FranciscoJavier.pdf?sequence=1).